# is this tricky in linq? Regex with Linq combo

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model with a property string that can be the format "00000044" so assuming I'm querying a List of

```
public class Foo
{
     private string MemberNo { get; set; }
}
```

populated from Entity Framework,

and our set includes the following:

```
"00000044" include this
"44000000" include this
"20440000" exclude this
```

how to write a query that will exclude anything with non-zero number to the left of our search criteria "44"

Is it possible to combine Regex with linq or is there a smarter way?

Ta

Comment: How about `0*44`? Matches none or any amount of zeros and then 44. You can also do `foo.MemberNo.TrimStart('0').StartsWith("44")` to see if the "44" is the first non-zero match.

Comment: hey thanks for response. could you show me the linq query? We're ok with the 0*44 regex - just how to write the query - i forgot to add this is querying EF - apolz.

Comment: Read about the LIKE keyword in SQL queries, because you don't want to pull all the data and then filter it, but better filter it DB-wise.

Comment: ..once again displeased the SO gods...

Comment: @MikeW are you talking about the down vote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var filteredFoos = myFoos
    .Where(foo => foo.MemberNo.TrimStart('0').StartsWith("44"));
```

Now this is if you want to bring back all `Foos`, but if you'd like to use the Entity Framework, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936718/user-trimstart-in-entity-framework-query) answer to translate it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = fooList.Where(foo => Regex.IsMatch(foo.MemberNo, @"^0*44\d*$"));
```

You'll also need to make the MemberNo property public.

**Edit**

Or alternatively, a regex-free version:

```
var result = fooList.Where(foo => foo.MemberNo.TrimStart('0').StartsWith("44"));
```

Comment: I'd stay away from regex because it sounds like the 44 may be an enterable search field.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich In that case it's fairly easy to build a regex pattern on the fly, and if you have it in a variable with a meaningful name I think it ends up being more readable.  Having said that see my edit for a regex-free version which would probably perform better if there's a lot of `Foo` to be filtered.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich And then I noticed it's the same as your answer.  Doh!

Comment: This was a great answer, the answer I marked is better for my overall understanding , but I appreciate the response - this works perfectly.