# Remove leading characters in string with linq to entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I need to remove leading zeros from a string. I'm trying to use `TrimStart('0')` in a linq to entities query and its not supported. I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936718/user-trimstart-in-entity-framework-query), but that solution didn't work for me, it says that function is not supported either. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Update: Using Sql Server and this is how I use it...

```
Where(c => c.StringToGet.Substring(SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%[^0]%", c.StringToGet).Value - 1) == stringToCompare)
```

Error... LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] PatIndex(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: What database do you use? What is the exact error if you use `SqlFunctions.PatIndex` and _how_ do you use it?

Comment: Well if you have to do it client side get them with leading zeros, and  then trim them locally. An other option given you are pulling them into a class would be to simply add a trimleadingzeros method to it.

Answer (score -1):

Do a ToList() on you query first. Then you can you use Trim as it won't be sql operation anymore.

Comment: You don't want this if `TRIM()` is supposed to be used in a `WHERE` clause, as it'll download the entire table and filter on the client.

Comment: Yeah, ideally I'd perform this on the database side.