# The method 'System.String TrimStart(Char[])' is only supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have been refactoring some of our clunky and not working LINQ queries lately when I find issues in our project. Here is one that is throwing me for a loop. I must confess, I am an android developer catapulted into C# with entity framework so I don't truly understand what is happening here. Nevertheless these queries look nearly the same to me (sprinkle a subquery here and a new join there). The first method will return without error:

```
public virtual IQueryable<ScratchGameDetailsModel> GetScratchGameDetails(string reconGUID)
    {
        var lotteryReconHeader = _lotteryReconHeaderRepository.GetAll().AsEnumerable(); // Changed on Nov 7,2017
        var lotteryReconDetails = _lotteryReconDetailRepository.GetAll().Where(s => s.ReconGUID == reconGUID).AsEnumerable();
        var lotteryGames = _lotteryGameRepository.GetAll().AsEnumerable();
        var lotteryActivations = _lotteryActivationRepository.GetAll().AsEnumerable();


        var response = (from ltrd in lotteryReconDetails
                        join lg in lotteryGames on ltrd.GameGUID equals lg.GameGUID
                        join la in lotteryActivations on lg.GameGUID equals la.GameGUID into LotteryActivations_join
                        from la in LotteryActivations_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join ltrh in lotteryReconHeader on ltrd.ReconGUID equals ltrh.ReconGUID // Added on Nov 7,2017
                        select new ScratchGameDetailsModel()
                        {
                            ReconGUID = ltrd.ReconGUID,
                            GameGUID = ltrd.GameGUID,
                            GameNumber = lg.GameNumber ?? Constants.Zero,
                            GameName = lg.GameName ?? String.Empty,
                            GameUPC = lg.GameUPC ?? string.Empty,
                            GameBin = lg.GameBin ?? Constants.Zero,
                            StartCount = ltrd.StartCount,
                            EndCount = ltrd.EndCount,
                            CashierSales = ltrd.CashierSales,
                            ExpectedStartCount = ltrd.ExpectedStartCount,
                            QtyOnRoll = lg.QtyOnRoll ?? Constants.Zero,
                            BookNumber = (la == null || la.BookNumber == null ? string.Empty : la.BookNumber.Split(new char[] { '-' }, 2).ElementAt(1).TrimStart('-')),
                            ReconTimeStamp = ltrh.ReconTimeStamp    // Added on Nov 7,2017
                        });

        return response.AsQueryable();
    }
```

You can probably tell why I don't like this method, 3 of those ienumerable lists are complete dumps of the DB tables of which later is joined. When the DB grows the query time of those variables increases. Complete waste of resources if you ask me. I have already fixed some methods that took over 5 minutes to populate data on another table due to the massive variable declaration and they are now being done in <1ms.

Here is the replacement method which should return all the same except now there is a subquery included. It also no longer sets ienumerable lists and just handles the query using DB context. This throws an error stating:

**The method 'System.String TrimStart(Char[])' is only supported in LINQ to Entities when there are no trim characters specified as arguments.**

```
public virtual IQueryable<ScratchGameDetailsModel> GetScratchGameDetailsNew(string reconGUID)
    {
        var newResponse = (from ltrd in _context.LotteryReconDetail
                           join lg in _context.LotteryGame on ltrd.GameGUID equals lg.GameGUID
                           join la in _context.LotteryActivation
                                on new
                                {
                                    lg.GameGUID,
                                    BookNumber =
                                    ((from la in _context.LotteryActivation
                                      where la.GameGUID == lg.GameGUID
                                      orderby la.row_id descending
                                      select new { la.BookNumber }).FirstOrDefault().BookNumber)
                                }
                                equals new { la.GameGUID, la.BookNumber } into la_join
                           from la in la_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           join ltrh in _context.LotteryReconHeader on ltrd.ReconGUID equals ltrh.ReconGUID
                           where ltrd.ReconGUID == reconGUID
                           select new ScratchGameDetailsModel()
                           {
                               ReconGUID = ltrd.ReconGUID,
                               GameGUID = ltrd.GameGUID,
                               GameNumber = lg.GameNumber ?? Constants.Zero,
                               GameName = lg.GameName ?? String.Empty,
                               GameUPC = lg.GameUPC ?? string.Empty,
                               GameBin = lg.GameBin ?? Constants.Zero,
                               StartCount = ltrd.StartCount,
                               EndCount = ltrd.EndCount,
                               CashierSales = ltrd.CashierSales,
                               ExpectedStartCount = ltrd.ExpectedStartCount,
                               QtyOnRoll = lg.QtyOnRoll ?? Constants.Zero,
                               BookNumber = (la == null || la.BookNumber == null ? string.Empty : la.BookNumber.Split(new char[] { '-' }, 2).ElementAt(1).TrimStart('-')),
                               ReconTimeStamp = ltrh.ReconTimeStamp
                           });

        return newResponse.AsQueryable();
    }
```

With my method, if I use the same operations (like setting variables) and use those for the query I receive "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Eureka! But why? The same raw SQL query has no issues and I would greatly like to know what the difference in LINQ is using DB context vs a queryable/enumerable context.

I have also modified those variable declarations and used AsQueryable() instead of AsEnumerable() so the entire list is not dumped but rather used as DB context in the query. If I am not mistaken that's the noticable difference between enumerable and queryable.

**This was resolved as @TheGeneral had pointed out. The calling assignment was updated to handle the value trimming as needed.**

```
BookNumber = (la == null || la.BookNumber == null ? string.Empty : la.BookNumber),
```

Then updated the calling method to handle the trim

```
var scratchGameDetails = _lotteryReconService.GetScratchGameDetailsNew(reconGUID).ToList().Select(s => new
            {
                s.ReconGUID,
                s.GameGUID,
                s.GameNumber,
                s.GameName,
                s.GameUPC,
                s.GameBin,
                s.StartCount,
                s.EndCount,
                s.CashierSales,
                s.ExpectedStartCount,
                RangeStart = gameStartCount,
                RangeEnd = useBaseZero ? (s.QtyOnRoll - 1) : s.QtyOnRoll,
                BookNumber = (s.BookNumber == string.Empty ? string.Empty : s.BookNumber.Split(new char[] { '-' }, 2).ElementAt(1).TrimStart('-')),
                s.ReconTimeStamp
            }).OrderByDescending(x => x.ReconTimeStamp).Distinct();
```

Comment: What do you think `AsEnumerable` does?

Comment: My assumption would be that `TrimStart()` gets converted `LTRIM` in SQL, and hence can't handle an actual value for the 'trimchars` parameter. But that's just a guess.  This is an older one but mentions this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936718/user-trimstart-in-entity-framework-query

Comment: @mjwillis, from my understanding it creates an enumerated list from the data retrieved from the query. The query that was previously used dumps the entire table into memory before doing any additional query functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- One is using in memory data (the repository code (*mega sigh*))
- The other pushing the projection back that the database, which is the one that is breaking

The whole reason it is throwing this exception is because the database doesn't understand the concept of `string.Trim()` also `Split` will throw as well

However, we can use any of the [String Canonical Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/canonical-functions).. though the easiest way is just project as you are an deal with the string manipulation your require after-the-fact in memory

```
BookNumber = (la == null || la.BookNumber == null ? string.Empty : la.BookNumber,
```

Note that we can use `LTRIM` as `EntityFunctions`, however it only trims space. Once again see [String Canonical Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/canonical-functions)

Comment: Thanks @TheGeneral. yes, im not a c# guy (yet) but it wasnt hard to figure out that the variable was a fat memory hog. You can see why i am re-writing some of these methods. I set the BookNumber as you have shown and in the method calling this service I handled the TrimStart(). Everything is functioning as expected. Updating the question with the resolution.