# Compare int and string with leading zeros with LINQ and SQLServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

#### Context

I have two entities in database with a one to many relationship that looks like this:

```
public class Material {
    public long MaterialCode { get; set; }
}

public class MaterialDescription {
   [StringLength(18, MinimumLength = 18)]
   public string MaterialCode { get; set; }
}
```

How can I use LINQ to query for all descriptions for a given material?

#### What I've tried?

```
    var descriptions = ctx.MaterialDescripions
        .Where(d => long.Parse(d.MaterialCode) == material.MaterialCode);
```

Gives error: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Int64 Parse(System.String)`.

```
    var descriptions = ctx.MaterialDescriptions
        .Where(d => d.MaterialCode.TrimStart('0') == material.MaterialCode.ToString());
```

Gives error: `System.String TrimStart(char[]) is only supported in LINQ to Entities when there are no trim characters specified as arguments`.

Comment: Have you tried `Where(d => d.MaterialCode == material.MaterialCode.ToString("D" + d.MaterialCode.Length))`?

Comment: Is the `MaterialDescription.MaterialCode` you're comparing against coming as an input to the method that queries the database? @HereticMonkey LINQ to SQL doesn't support `ToString` either.

Comment: @MattU Right, `StringFunctions.StringConvert(material.MaterialCode, d.MaterialCode.Length)`, from https://stackoverflow.com/q/1066760/215552

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Finally came with the solution!

Thanks to [Jeff Ogata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409259/jeff-ogata) with his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7936926/11917764)!

```
    var descriptions = ctx.MaterialDescriptions
        Where(d => d.MaterialCode.Substring(SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%[^0]%", d.MaterialDescription) == material.MaterialCode.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server (assuming that's what you're using) will let you cast a string with leading zeros to a bigint, so you could just construct the SQL query yourself:

```
var descriptions = ctx.MaterialDescriptions
    .SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM MaterialDescriptions WHERE CAST(MaterialCode AS bigint) = @p0",
              material.MaterialCode);
```

You can read more about raw SQL queries [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery).